# Updating outer count from inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that takes a list of supervisor ID's from `TableA` and needs to find all of the employees that report to them which is easy on a simple join as its one level deep.

In the employee record, we have their Hiredate.

I need to update `TableA` with the count of people that have been there over 1 year and less than 1 year.

`IF(DATEDIFF(day,Hiredate,GETDATE())>365)` would be how I would think we would do that. Just add `1` to a counter for each over the 1 year and `1` to the counter for each under 1 year.

The issue with this is I have no idea where to start on it. I have the query that joins the tables and gets down to the list of the employees but not sure how to structure the case / update statement.

```
SELECT A.[QID], B.[FirstName], B.[LastName], B.[EmpID],
   (
        SELECT FirstName, LastName, HireDate
        FROM dbo.EmpTable
        WHERE SupEmpID = B.EmpID
        FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
        -- IF(DATEDIFF(day,Hiredate,GETDATE())>365) add +1 to longTerm var else add +1 to shortTerm var
   )
FROM dbo.attritionCounts AS A
JOIN empTable AS B ON A.QID = B.QID
```

- This would be within some type of loop that updates per manager it joins.
- Update TableA SET longTerm = blah, shortTerm = blah where QID = A.QID

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Here is an SQLfiddle of the example structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3a14

using the `attritionCount` table, I need to search the `Employees` table and find out the number of people that report to `attritionCount.QID` that have been here over a year and less than a year

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your desired output to clarify your question please?

Comment: my answer is updated to reflect the sql fiddle test data.  Though not substantially changed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, if I understood you correctly:

```
update ac set ShortTerm = isnull(sq.ShortTerm, 0), LongTerm = isnull(sq.LongTerm, 0)
from dbo.AttritionCount ac
  left join (
    select e.Supervisor,
      sum(case when dateadd(year, 1, e.HireDate) <= getdate() then 1 else 0 end) as [LongTerm],
      sum(case when dateadd(year, 1, e.HireDate) > getdate() then 1 else 0 end) as [ShortTerm]
    from dbo.Employees e
    group by e.Supervisor
  ) sq on sq.Supervisor = ac.QID;
```

EDIT: updated code according to Fiddle. As it appears, the `DATEDIFF()` function behaves somewhat differently from what I expected, so I have changed conditions within `case` statements.

Comment: The one thing I dont understand is this line `sq on sq.ManagerId = m.Id;` where is `sq` defined as a table?

Comment: sq is short for "subquery".  It is the query where the aggregation and summation is performed.

Comment: Okay, I tried it and I am a little confused; I may have just adapted it wrong but it put a 1 in all of the long term fields which is correct because they are all over a year. However, it only put a one even though theres like 15 people under each manager. My employee table needs to get all the employees where `MgrQID = m.QID`

Comment: @SBB, it is an alias of the sub-query where aggregates are calculated. It is defined in exactly the same line, right after the closing bracket.

Comment: @SBB, well, you can update your OP with tables' DDL and sample data, so that will be no confusion over table/column names.

Comment: Updated the OP with a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of things you want to be doing a SUM() of employees which match the criteria, aggregated (GROUPED) by the supervisors ID.

Assuming this is the case, here's an example of using a conditional statement in an aggregation function, based on my understanding of the case you've provided:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Employees
    ([QID] varchar(9), [First] varchar(9), [Last] varchar(10), [HireDate] Date, [Supervisor] varchar(6), [Title] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO #Employees
    ([QID], [First], [Last], [HireDate], [Supervisor], [Title])
VALUES
    ('Q12345', 'Nicole', 'Bartlett', '2014-11-07', NULL, 'President'),
    ('Q92019', 'Christine', 'Rubio', '2014-11-07', 'Q12345', 'VP'),
    ('Q24285', 'Pablo', 'Werner', '2014-10-07', 'Q92019', 'Director'),
    ('Q32422', 'Holly', 'Fernandez', '2014-11-07', 'Q92019', 'Director'),
    ('Q78841', 'Chadwick', 'Trevino', '2014-11-07', 'Q32422', 'Manager')
;



CREATE TABLE #attritionCount
    ([QID] varchar(9), [shortTerm] INT, [LongTerm] INT)
;

INSERT INTO #attritionCount (QID, shortTerm, longTerm)
  SELECT
    sup.QID
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN emp.HireDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN emp.HireDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM #Employees emp
    INNER JOIN #Employees sup ON emp.Supervisor = sup.QID
  GROUP BY sup.QID

SELECT * FROM #attritionCount
```

The important thing here is that you're summing the result of the case statement.  Be careful here that you are only returning one row per employee/supervisor relationship.